# Avoiding ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating the table as below in the sql file, which will be called everytime there is a new file to process. So everytime a new file comes, I will drop this table and create again and load. When I am calling this from shell script, this table gets dropped and created successfully, but along with this i get an error as below. Any idea how to avoid this.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Table Drop and create sql file :

```
DROP TABLE SCHEMA.TEMP_SOURCE;
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TEMP_SOURCE(
COL 1 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
COL 2 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
COL 3 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
);
/
EXIT;
```

Comment: You're saying that the drop and create are successful, but an error is raised. Either the error is raised by a different part of the script, or the drop and create are raising it in which case one or both of them are failing.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The issue is the slash in the end of the script. The create statement is executed twice, since it is in the buffer.

Comment: @David There is only drop and create in the script, and I get table dropped successufully and created successfully, after that i get this error. When i check the table in the backend its created successfully.

Comment: If its because of slash, then how to avoid it. If i remove slash will it work ?

Comment: Just follow my suggestion in the answer, there is a working test case.

Answer (score 6):

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

That's because, you have put a slash `/` in the end of the script.

> );
>
> /

Due to which, the previous statement in the buffer is executed again. Which means, the **CREATE TABLE statement is executed twice**.

Remove the slash from the end. The semi-colon is enough as statement terminator for individual queries.

This is how I would do:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TEMP_SOURCE';
  3  EXCEPTION
  4     WHEN OTHERS THEN
  5        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
  6           RAISE;
  7        END IF;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEMP_SOURCE
  2    (
  3      COL_1 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  4      COL_2 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  5      COL_3 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Having said that, you have multiple issues in the script.

> COL 1 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),

You cannot have a space in the column name. `COL 1` is an invalid column name. You will get **Invalid identifier error**.

Another issue:

> COL 3 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
>
> );

There is an extra **comma** in the **end of the column list**.

Comment: Thanks @lalit. Dont worry about the space in column and comma, its for just illustration purpose.  I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit, removing the slash has worked. adding it after drop, will give an error after drop, as it was for create. So there are no slashes in the sql now, and not getting any error. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please mark it answered, would help others.

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify your script as below:

```
DROP TABLE SCHEMA.TEMP_SOURCE
/
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.TEMP_SOURCE(
COL 1 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
COL 2 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
COL 3 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
)
/
EXIT;
```

Comment: adding slash after each command, resulted in error for both the stmt, so removed both and worked fine. Thank you.